# Generating primary keys of a particular format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb6

I have a program used by my company written by a 3rd party that does not expose an API. That vendor has  no plans to ever add one.  The program uses SQL Server for the back end data store.  It would be extremely beneficial to be able to add records to the database for integrating into new applications.

Every table in this database has a primary key column called Id, its a nvarchar(12) data type and by using SQL Server Profiler, I have determined that this value is generated by the source code, not by anything inside SQL Server.  From some free decompilers I have tried, it appears much of the software was written in VB6.  It also appears that the primary keys are somewhat related to time, and I say this because an order by on the Id column always yields the same order as the CreatedOn date.

Here are some examples of the primary key values:

```
5RN0PZ36TWM
5RN0Q036UAZ
5RN0Q136V20
5RN0Q136VF3
5RN0Q236VS6
5RN0Q236W5O
5RN0Q336WIR
5RN0Q336WW9
5RN0Q436X9S
5RN0Q436XMU
5RN0Q536Y0D
5RN0Q536YDV
```

They are always alphanumeric and 'A' is greater than '9'.  Also, the Id values are usually between 9 and 12 characters long.

Basically, I want to know if anyone has seen a method in VB6 that will return a value in this type of format, or maybe another unique key generator used in VB6.  I am using C# to write my programs so if there is another way to duplicate this type of value in C#, that would be nice to know also.

Comment: do you have to stick with that particular format...? if it's a nvarchar(12) why can't you come up with your own method of creating  / generating unique keyId's

Comment: It's our main production system, I am deathly afraid of changing something that will mess up some design constraint I don't know about.  I also do not want the vendor to make assumptions or accusations regarding database errors if we start inserting our own records.  We have, on several occasions, had to send copies of the database for them to come up with some patch scripts.

Comment: Production, Test, or Dev really doesn't matter in my opinion there are tons of ways to get around stubborn vendors whom like to hold company's hostage via crappy code implementation and support.. figure out what values are getting inserted, then come up with your own mechanism that will not break the business flow.. this is nothing to be afraid of .. "Think outside of the BOX...|"

Comment: Also who owns the database.. your company or the vendor.. I would hope the company owns it's own data base.. also if the vendor is not being helpful why not suggest locking them out of the system.. this sounds like 2 issues here .. `IT` and possible `Legal / Contract` sounds like a weak company that you are working for sorry..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I will see what I can do, thanks

Comment: if you need help on any of this or something specific please don't hesitate to ask online there are several of us developers whom have been in your same situation in the past and or present so like I said don't be afraid to ask.. good luck